# Prove one case of the Reverse Triangle Inequality $|x-y|≥|x|-|y|$ for all reals $x$ and $y$

Tags: inequality

Prove this inequality for all reals $x$ and $y$:

$$|x-y|≥|x|-|y|$$

Comment: Hint: $x=(x-y)+y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality),

$$\begin{align}|x| &= |(x-y) + y|\\
&\le |x-y| + |y|\end{align}$$

Rearrange the terms to get $|x-y| \ge |x| - |y|$.